# CST to UTC Conversion in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to convert my CST `DateTime` column to an UTC `DateTime` column.

What will be the difference it is -5 or +5?

```
SELECT DATEADD(HH, -5, '2018-06-13 11:13:33.24')
```

Thanks.

Comment: CST is [UTC −6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone). `c = u − 6`. Solve for `u`.

Comment: Take care that CST changes to CDT in zones where DST is in effect, and converting local date/times that have already had DST applied to them to UTC can't be done unambiguously. You can do this for one-off queries where the transition is not a problem, but not structurally.

Comment: Your question of is it + or - 5 hours can be easily solved with a google search. The bigger picture is to not blow up your data by converting it incorrectly between UTC and CST/CDT based on which DST it was previously. Moving forward write a datediff function between local TZ and UTC and apply that hour difference. That will allow you to accommodate either CST or CDT as it happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how Windows interprets the current CST offset you can navigate to the

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones
```

and Find the `CST` value.

Currently it is having it's DST applied so `-6 + (DST+1) = -5`